# Usar substring para sacar contenido de un texto

Tags: java, substring

Necesito sacar de una cadena de texto las 15 letras de antes y las 15 de después cada vez que aparezca en la cadena la palabra "ojala",y también todas las frases que se encuentre entre comillas , sin las comillas. He intentado varias formas con substring, pero no doy con la tecla.
pd.Es la primera vez que publico, espero no haber infringido ningún código ético de la plataforma, xD.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Bueno... para empezar, si no vemos que probaste, dificil que podamos decirte que hiciste mal. mostranos que intentaste y te vamos a poder ayudar. Tene en cuenta que aca no hacemos ejercicios, si te ayudamos con problemas puntuales.

Comment: Coloca el código que estas probando para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Disculpad, como dije era la primera vez que publicaba, recién comienzo en esto de programar y mis nociones son muy básicas, me pasé horas buscando porque no sabía ni cómo comenzar. Actualmente logré sacar las frases de las comillas,así: `for (int i=0;i<(texto.length()-1);i++ ) { if(texto.charAt(i) == '«') { System.out.println(i); System.out.println( texto.substring( i + 1, texto.substring(i + 1).indexOf("»") + i + 1 ) ); }` Sigo con sin saber cómo sacar las 15 letras de antes y después cada vez que aparece una palabra en concreto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo haría de la siguiente manera:

```
    String x ="aaaaaaaaa_tu_texto_aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaojalaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    String[] split=x.split("ojala");
    // split convierte tu texto en un array separando por la cadena ojala
    // con este array, solo queda imprimir los 15 primeros y 15 ultimos caracteres de cada posicion
    // con la excepcion de la primera y ultima posicion, que son casos especiales
    for(int i =0 ; i<split.length;i++){
        if(i==0){// En la primera posicion solo imprimimos los 15 ultimos
            System.out.println(split[i].substring(split[i].length()-16,split[i].length()));
        }
        else if(i==split.length-1){// en la ultima posicion , solo los 15 primeros
            System.out.println(split[i].substring(0,15));
        }
        else{ // en el resto de posiciones, imprimimos ambas.
            System.out.println(split[i].substring(split[i].length()-16,split[i].length()));
            System.out.println(split[i].substring(0,15));
        }
    }
```

Notese que igual me baila algún carácter en los `substring` .

Saludos !!!

PD: También hay que añadir pequeñas comprobaciones de que existan mas de 15 caracteres entre cada aparición de "ojala", y al principio y al final.